# Traefik,multiple frontend rules to one docker container

Tags: docker-compose, traefik

I did search the manual but really couldn't make it very clear, even using the keywords to google that.

I need to proxy the `/_` to the API container, some rule like that `www.mydomain.com/_ => API container`

There is already a specified domain point to this API container
`api.mydomain.com => API container`

This is my `docker-compose.yml`, all I want is to add a rule that proxy the `/_` to this container too.

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  testapi:

    image: git.xxxx.com/api/core/test:latest

    restart: always

    networks:
      - web
      - default

    expose:
      - "80"

    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.port=80"
      - "traefik.docker.network=web"
      - "traefik.backend=testapi"
      #this domain is used for app
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:api.test.mydomain.com"
      #this is used for website.All I want is prxy "https://www.test.mydomain.com/_/" to this container
      - "traefik.frontend.rule1=Host:www.test.mydomain.com;PathPrefixStrp:/_"
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use segment labels:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
 testapi:
   image: git.xxxx.com/api/core/test:latest
   restart: always
   networks:
     - web
     - default
   expose:
     - "80"
   labels:
     - "traefik.enable=true"
     - "traefik.port=80"
     - "traefik.docker.network=web"
     #this domain is used for app
     - "traefik.foo.frontend.rule=Host:api.test.mydomain.com"
     - "traefik.bar.frontend.rule=Host:www.test.mydomain.com,m.test.mydomain.com;PathPrefixStrp:/_"
```

https://docs.traefik.io/v1.6/configuration/backends/docker/#on-containers-with-multiple-ports-segment-labels

Comment: Work like a charm